# struts2 <s:select

Tags: java, struts2

I am trying to populate the `<s:select` options using a struts action class. How do I initialiase the class from within a jsp? So instead of using something like myjsp.action - I have myjsp.jsp and invoke myjsp.action from within the jsp itself.

Thanks

Comment: Please note that in Struts2 most of the heavy-lifting is done by the interceptors. So I am not very sure how you would be able to achieve population of s:select box by calling the action directly from a jsp. You would need to somehow call the whole struts2 stack than a just an action to achieve this.

Comment: Also can you let us know why you want to do such a thing than plugging struts2 the "usual" way and achieving s:select population?

Comment: I am including a page like so - <%@ include file="/forms/searchform.jsp"%> searchform.jsp contains an <s:select dropdown. How can I populate the <s:select from within the jsp? From reading online tutorials I need to invoke the corresponding .action class for the jsp. Is there another way? Thanks

Comment: Sounds bad. As peakit says above, you should normally populate your select from you just executed action. That is the normal good Struts2 way. Do you understand this, and do you have good reasons to do something different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon your explanation in the comment, I feel this is how you should be doing this:

```
User -> HTTPRequest -> Action (populate data required for s:select in HTTPRequest)
                          |
                          V
User <- HTTPResponse <- OnSuccess, show a final.jsp (this jsp can include the searchForm.jsp)
```

The `s:select` in searchForm will be rendered correctly.